# Unity -- Stop Rigidbody from Moving Player

Tags: unity3d

So I'm working on an RPG and I have some colliders which of course, don't work without rigidbodies. To stop rigidbodies from moving you, you must put constrains on positions, but then there is no collision... How do I fix this?

With constrains:

[image: with constrains]

Without constrains:

[image: without constrains]